# Why is this nginx virtual host not working?

Tags: nginx

I have a server in the ip lets say 150.150.150.150

It has the route /var/www/html/index.html

I go to my domain provider and configure the following records

```
URL Redirect Record @ http://www.mydomains.com/ Unmasked
A Record myapp 150.150.150.150
A Record @ 150.150.150.150
```

Then I go to my nginx server which has a couple of sites running and do the following virtual host file named myapp

```
server {
   server_name 150.150.150.150 myapp.mydomains.com www.myapp.mydomains.com;
   root /var/www/html/index.html;
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html =404;
   }
}
```

I link it to sites-enabled

I relaod the server but it doesnt work.

I dont know how to debug it

Note that I have another domain pointed to the same server, it points to two different apps using subdomains.

EDIT: I have just noticed that it works, but it redirects me to another app that I have in another route, so that doesnt make sense, it should redirect to that route , if its not in the conf file

Answer (score 0):

Cache issue, worked fine with private browser

Comment: Chrome has aggressive caching which can cause these headaches, FYI.